# Cannot instantiate the type error... but code is right?

Tags: java, instantiation, instantiationexception

So I have a big issue. I am getting the "cannot instantiate the type Robot" error when I try to make a new instance of the Robot class. I fully understand what this error means and when it occurs, but I do not understand why I am getting it. I swear, my code is correct. Maybe there is one small error in the code that I just do not see? Any help?

The code getting the error is the RobotWorld class:

```
public class RobotWorld extends JPanel{

Robot robot;

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public RobotWorld(){
        robot = new Robot();
        this.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    }
}
```

And the Robot.java class is:

```
public class Robot {

    public Robot(){

    }

}
```

I am getting the error on the line "robot = new Robot();" in RobotWorld.java code. Basically, anywhere I try to instantiate a new Robot object in RobotWorld, it will give me an error. I even tried doing it when I created the instance variable robot, still didn't work.

Both of these classes are in the same package, so I don't see how it can be some kind of class scope error. Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error?

Note, I restarted Eclipse a few times to make sure it wasn't just Eclipse acting up.

Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible that you've accidentally defined `Robot` in multiple places? For example, is it possible that `RobotWorld` contains a `private interface Robot { ... }` somewhere, or something like that, that you intended to delete and then forgot about? (To test this, click on the `Robot` in `Robot robot;`, and then hit F3 to go to the declaration that Eclipse thinks is applicable.)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

It appears you may have imported the `import com.sun.glass.ui.Robot;` which is an abstract class and cannot be instantiated.

Be sure to remove any import statements for the wrong Robot class.

You may want to consider renaming your own Robot class as well to not get them confused.

Comment: If his class represents a robot, why should he rename it then? That's what namespaces are for after all. + even if he was using `Java.awt.Robot`, the error should not come up since awt.Robot is not abstract and should be instantiatable.

Comment: You can't instantiate a Robot class just like that you will get a compiler error since you do not catch the AWTException it can throw. We do not know his exact error since he did not post it. Also, it was just a recommendation to prevent confusion. I don't see why you would downvote.

Comment: Rouby, actually looks like I was correct, he was importing the wrong Robot class only it seems he was importing `import com.sun.glass.ui.Robot;`

Comment: I downvoted because I dont consider this a valid answer. In his title he specified the error 'Cannot instantiate the type'. new java.awt.Robot gives an AWTException.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I have updated my answer to correct that mistake and with what I believe may be the direct issue.

Comment: I removed my downvote because you clarified your answer. But still I think this should have been a comment to get further information of the question and not hunt for a wild guess which Robot class he imported.

Comment: I wont argue that point but it was not just a wild guess, I figured it had to do with a different robot class but just referenced the wrong one off the top of my head. But anyways thanks for the heads up.